# Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0. Why this Error?

Tags: react-native, maps

Quite new to using react native Maps.

I am trying to use react native Maps. I followed a step by step tutorial and I came to this Error :

```
    J:\reactnativeTut\mapsExample>react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
(node:20720) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Jetifier found 1415 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
26 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 24 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\xxx\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1cb9b9ea592aa2ea85233be252327dcf\appcompat-1.1.0\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

     C:\Users\xxx\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1cb9b9ea592aa2ea85233be252327dcf\appcompat-1.1.0\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

     C:\Users\xxx\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\639e914bfc1efa21e36199d3ff2c5eef\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

     C:\Users\xxx\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\639e914bfc1efa21e36199d3ff2c5eef\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

     C:\Users\xxx\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1cb9b9ea592aa2ea85233be252327dcf\appcompat-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:2772:5-2795:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/textFontWeight not found.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081


J:\reactnativeTut\mapsExample>
```

What i do not understand is why i am getting this Error.

My Code is looking something like this

**build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
   // ext {
   //     buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
   //     minSdkVersion = 16
   //     compileSdkVersion = 29
   //     targetSdkVersion = 29
   // }
    
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 26
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "26.1.0"
        playServicesVersion = "17.0.0" // or find latest version
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.mapsexample">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
      <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
     android:value="API_KEY"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "mapsExample",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.4",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.27.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.12.10",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "25.5.1",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "jest": "25.5.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Kindly help. I am very new to using maps. I have since been looking out to Seeing something that can actually be of help, nothing to show.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using this command

```
cd android
gradlew clean
```

if also this won't work then please check the below error because its throwing error of
**Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.** which means debug resouces have some issues. since you see the path is of cache that's why I asked you to clean the gradlew.

```
res\values-v28\values-v28.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

I kind of managed to fix the Error.
Hope this would help someone in Future.

Shows the Maps now. But they are tiny :(

The code Error  was in the `android\build.gradle` file. renaming the `ext` section like this shows the maps. Although the maps were quite tiny

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 29
    targetSdkVersion = 29
    supportLibVersion = "29.1.0"
    playServicesVersion = "17.0.0" // or find latest version
    androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
}
```

I hope it helps someone Later on.